# Calculating maximum physical memory

Tags: memory

I have been given the format for page table entries:

```
Bit  23: Valid Bit
Bit  22: Modify Bit
Bits 22-18: LRU Bits
Bits 17-0:  Frame Number
```

Im told that the system uses 32-bit virtual addresses and pages that are 8192 bytes in size.

How could I calculate the maximum amount of physical memory the system can contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 18 bits for page numbers. How many possible numbers (and therefore pages) can be represented by 18 bits?

From the above you'll find how many pages there can be. Then each page has 8192 bytes. How many bytes are there in all possible pages?

Comment: So are you saying the page number is the same as the frame number? I would say 2^18 is the maximum amount of physical memory the system can contain?

Comment: First question: right. Second question: wrong, please reread the answer.

Comment: Ok. So we have 18 bits for page numbers. I would say you could represent 2^18 numbers with 18 bits, so 2^18 pages. So if each page has 8192 bytes, multiply that by 2^18, that gives you the maximum amount of physical memory in bytes?

Comment: This question as it was posted, has been fully covered. Create new questions. Don't forget to upvote and accept helpful answers.